# How to find the name of the first input in form but exclude an input with the name '__RequestVerificationToken'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can use the following statement to get the name of the first input field in a form, however the RequestVerificationToken happens to be the first input in the form so, how do I exclude this?

```
var fullName = $('#ForgotLoginForm').find('input').first().attr('name');
```

Comment: This `RequestVerificationToken` is an Id or that element has a specific attr?

Comment: Yes, how do I exclude something with an id of "__RequestVerificationToken"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this `__RequestVerificationToken` is an Id, use this selector `input:not(#__RequestVerificationToken)`

```js
var fullName = $('#ForgotLoginForm')
  .find('input:not(#__RequestVerificationToken)')
  .first()
  .attr('name');

console.log(fullName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='ForgotLoginForm'>
  <input id='__RequestVerificationToken' name='__RequestVerificationToken'>
  <input id='ele' name='EleFromStack'>
</div>
```

Comment: Typo apologies. Noticed that it was in the name attribute not id. How does that change things?

Comment: Never mind got it, .not('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]')

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `not` selector:

```js
$('#ForgotLoginForm').find('input').not('#__RequestVerificationToken').first().css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ForgotLoginForm">
  <input id="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input id="a" name="b" value="c" />
  <input id="d" name="e" value="f" />
</form>
```

In the above example I just set the background color on that input as red, but you can take the value of the `name` attribute just like in your question, using `attr('name')`.

Comment: Just saw that the attribute is 'name', not 'id', what would I need to adjust?